# Periodic group with bounded subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for infinite periodic groups $G$ (by periodic I mean that every element has finite order), whose finite subgroups are not arbitrarily large. I.e. there is a constant $M$ such that for any finite subgroup $H$ of $G$ one has $|H| \leq M$.
Note that it is not enough to consider infinite groups of finite exponent.

A class of groups that satisfy these requirements are the Tarski Monster groups. Here one can take $M = p$ for some prime $p$.

Are there any other notable examples? Is there a particular name for these groups?